# DOCKER - space LEFT

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

We had a problem when docker gives error:

> Service 'php' failed to build: devmapper: Thin Pool has 158303 free
> data blocks which is less than minimum required 163840 free data
> blocks. Create more free space in thin pool or use dm.min_free_space
> option to change behavior

There is more than enough space on the disk itself so to diagnose this we used `docker info` and saw a limit

> Data Space Total: 107.4GB

Then, we switched from `Storage Driver: devicemapper` to `overlay2`

Questions:

1. Is there a way to see how much space is available for `overlay2`?
2. If not, what is the default disk limit for above?
3. It seems the only way to clean space is to run `docker prune ...` manually whenever disk space limit is reached, is there a way to keep image cache selectively to decrease build time?
4. Are we really stuck with manual `docker prune ...` every time when `free data blocks which is less than minimum required 163840 free data blocks` error occurs?

Thank you.

Comment: The overlay2 driver doesn't have this "data blocks" concept; it should be able to use the entire host disk.  `docker info` shouldn't even show it.

Comment: @DavidMaze right